# Console output from toString isn't formatting correctly in Java for a "shopping cart" type application. Am I missing something simple?

Tags: java, tostring

Denizens of stack overflow, I call upon your help and grand wisdom.

**Problem: driver print is printing pretty much all that I need it to, but the first row also prints the entirety of the information as well in one long line. I've noticed the format doesn't stay for copy/pasting my console putput so I'll attempt to describe it. It prints out, neatly enough, a formatted table with the info I need. It's just that the top row duplicates the info as well. It appears to be the exact same print, just with no new lines**

I have this shopping cart application. All is done and now I'm working on the toString formatting for the receipt looking printout in console. As this encompasses 7 or so different classes I won't post all of the code, but just the cart, driver, and parent class as it's my best guess that's where the problem is originating. If more is needed please let me know and I can post what I have.

Copy/paste of console output

---

[Beef   2   1   2, Nametag  5   2   10, Wetfood 2   15  30, Catnip  3   2   6, Dryfood  20  1   20, Goldfish    5   true    1   Goldie  true, Small 150.5   true    1   Minx    1   4   , Small 200.28  true    2   Fluffy  0   3   ]Beef   2   1   2
Nametag 5   2   10
Wetfood 2   15  30
Catnip  3   2   6
Dryfood 20  1   20
Goldfish    5   true    1   Goldie  true
Small   150.5   true    1   Minx    1   4
Small   200.28  true    2   Fluffy  0   3

```
    public class ShoppingDriver{
                                    
    
        public ShoppingDriver(int max) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            PetStoreItem Beef = new PetFood("Beef", 2.00, 1);
            PetStoreItem Fluffy = new Mammal("Small", 200.275, true, 2, "Fluffy", 0, 3);
            PetStoreItem Minx = new Mammal("Small", 150.50, true, 1, "Minx", 1, 4);
            PetStoreItem Goldie = new Fish("Goldfish", 5.00, true, 1, "Goldie", true);
            PetStoreItem Catnip = new PetFood("Catnip", 3.00, 2);
            PetStoreItem Dryfood = new PetFood("Dryfood", 20.00, 1);
            PetStoreItem Wetfood = new PetFood("Wetfood", 2.00, 15);
            PetStoreItem Nametag = new PetFood("Nametag", 5.00, 2);
            
            Cart one = new Cart(8);
            one.add(Beef);
            one.add(Nametag);
            one.add(Wetfood);
            one.add(Catnip);
            one.add(Dryfood);
            one.add(Goldie);
            one.add(Minx);
            one.add(Fluffy);
            System.out.println(one);
    
        }
    
    }


public class Cart {
    private PetStoreItem[] itemsList;
    private int numItems;

    public Cart(int max) {
        itemsList = new PetStoreItem[max];
        numItems = 0;
    }

    public void add(PetStoreItem itemToAdd) {
        itemsList[numItems++] = itemToAdd;

    }

    public int size() {
        int size = itemsList.length;
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String output = "";
        output += Arrays.toString(itemsList);
        for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
            output += itemsList[i] + "\n";
        }
        return output;
    }

}


    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    
    public abstract class PetStoreItem {
        private String description;
        private double price;
        public static final DecimalFormat DF2 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        
        public PetStoreItem(String description, double price) {
            this.description = description;
            this.price = price;
        }
        
        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }
        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
        
        public void setDescription(String desc) {
            description = desc;
        }
        
        public void setPrice(Double cost) {
            price = cost;
        }
        double itemTotalCost() {
            return price;
        }
        public String toString() {
            String output = "";
            output += description + "\t" + DF2.format(price) + "\t";
            return output;
        }
    }
```

I have 4 additional child classes (Mammal, Fish, PetFood, Pet). If these may prove useful I'll provide them. Worthy of note, I did remove the super.toString from the cart class as it was creating an error in the console similar to "CFS@13756af". If I remember correctly, this is caused my an attempt to print an object without a toString. Anyway, I removed the super from the cart and that fixed it.
I'm now at the final step of just formatting my toString with labels and making it look nice and I for the love of me haven't been able to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: `Arrays.toString(itemsList);` and looping are essentially doing the same thing. Do either one of them. Not both.

Comment: The ```toString()``` method of ```cart``` seems wrong to me. Why would you first do this ```output += Arrays.toString(itemsList);```  and then manually append all the items again?

Comment: how do you want the output to look like,

Comment: Hey guys, thank you so much. That fixed it. I removed output += Arrays.toString(itemsList); and that cleaned the top line right up. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this line in Cart#toString(), and if removing it helps:

output += Arrays.toString(itemsList);